# Do most Smartphones support J2ME

Tags: mobile, java-me, mobile-application

Since there are different standards to develop Apps for the different Mobile Platforms, perhaps J2ME maybe a common base for all.

Is J2ME supported by most modern phones, particularly those by Apple(they tend to be different from others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Android, iOS don't support J2ME.

Comment: phoneME runs on Android, so you can run J2ME fine on Android.
http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/28
You can even place MIDlet icons on your desktop, so you can launch MIDlets just like any native or web-app.

Answer (score 1):

Actually J2ME is supported by most older phones and less so modern phones. Most of the phones prior to the big touchscreen breakthrough of iPhone supported three standards.

- J2ME - which applied to the largest subset of GSM phones
- BREW - A proprietary OS and software package for CDMA phones on the
  Verizon network
- Symbian - A [proprietary](http://symbian.nokia.com/blog/2011/04/04/not-open-source-just-open-for-business/) technology for another subset of GSM
  phones produced for Nokia phones primarily and maintained by Nokia.

J2ME is the most popular of the bunch and applied to most of the phones you would see from the likes of Motorola, LG, Audiovox to name a few.

Some select Windows Mobile phones today also support J2ME, but it's hardly a standard anymore.

You can see which phones currently support J2ME by going to [PhoneScoop](http://www.phonescoop.com/phones/finder.php) phone finder and filtering by Java-ME.

---

http://www.phonescoop.com/phones/finder.php

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Perhaps, it may be possible to run the JAR files on any platform with suitable converters, right?

Comment: I think so, you may have better luck with Android.

Comment: All Nokia phones that are based on the Symbian OS and the Series40 platform continue to support(and extend) JavaME.

Comment: Also, since development in BlackBerry and Android is primarily Java Based, they would surely have facility to Interpret the J2ME codes.

Comment: @Gorkem: Yes, I am aware that Nokias Symbian sets continue to support it. My question was based on this fact, since Nokia supports it without owning  it, other platforms may as well be eager to do same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install kJVM into a phone then you can install any J2ME application on it. But remember j2me have lots of restrictions .